How to define correctly a converter in ModelMapper library for DTO
I have two JPA entities: Person and Address and three DTOs called: PersonDto, AddressDto and BasicAddressDto. The class AddressDto extends BasicAddressDto.
PersonDto has a property called address (type: BasicAddressDto).
However, I'd like to force ModelMapper to use an instance of AddressDto instead of BasicAddressDto during mapping from Person to PersonDto.
I wrote a following converter:
Converter<Address, BasicAddressDto> CONVERTER =
            new AbstractConverter<Address, BasicAddressDto>() {
                @Override
                protected BasicAddressDto convert(Address address) {
                    return new AddressDto(address.getUuid(), address.getStreet(), address.getCity());
                }
            };

and ModelMapper configuration:
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.typeMap(Person.class, PersonDto.class).addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(CONVERTER)
                .map(Person::getAddress, PersonDto::setAddress));

Unfortunately, I am getting an error:
org.modelmapper.ConfigurationException: ModelMapper configuration errors:

1) Not able to skip address., because there are already nested properties are mapped: [address.uuid.]. Do you skip the property after the implicit mappings mapped? We recommended you to create an empty type map, and followed by addMappings and implicitMappings calls

How to fix that error?
The rest of the code is as follows:
    @Test
    void test() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.typeMap(Person.class, PersonDto.class).addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(CONVERTER)
                .map(Person::getAddress, PersonDto::setAddress));

        Person person = new Person(
                UUID.randomUUID(), "John Doe", new Address(UUID.randomUUID(), "Palm Ave", "Gold Potato City"));
        PersonDto personDto = modelMapper.map(person, PersonDto.class);

        assertThat(personDto.getAddress()).isInstanceOf(AddressDto.class);
    }


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Person {
    private UUID uuid;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Address {
    private UUID uuid;
    private String street;
    private String city;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class PersonDto {
    private UUID uuid;
    private String name;
    private BasicAddressDto address;
}

@Getter
@Setter
class AddressDto extends BasicAddressDto {
    private String street;
    private String city;

    public AddressDto(UUID uuid, String street, String city) {
        super(uuid);
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class BasicAddressDto {
    private UUID uuid;
}



See https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/724.

Worked as a charm.
